# Program crashes, when calling capsulated std::begin from member-class

Tags: c++, reference, crash, iterator, member

My production-code crashed and I couldn't find the reason, 
so I searched for the root of the evil and succeeded now to build a minimal example, where variant B reproduces the error.

Maybe someone can help me out to understand whats the problem here is?

Why does variant B crashes and variant A not? For me, it seems, that both variants should have the same behavior?

**The output from the visual studio 2017 debugger:**

```
void _Adopt(const _Container_base12 *_Parent) _NOEXCEPT
        {   // adopt this iterator by parent
        if (_Parent == 0)
            {   // no future parent, just disown current parent
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
            _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
            _Orphan_me();
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
            }
        else
            {   // have a parent, do adoption
            _Container_proxy *_Parent_proxy = _Parent->_Myproxy;

 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
            if (_Myproxy != _Parent_proxy)
                {   // change parentage
                _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
                _Orphan_me();
                _Mynextiter = _Parent_proxy->_Myfirstiter;   <--- MARKED HERE
                _Parent_proxy->_Myfirstiter = this;
                _Myproxy = _Parent_proxy;
                }

 #else /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
            _Myproxy = _Parent_proxy;
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
            }
        }
```

**Minimal, compilable example:**

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct IteratorCapsule
{
    const T * m_ptrObj;
    IteratorCapsule(const T &refObj) : m_ptrObj(&refObj) {}
    typename T::const_iterator begin() const {  return std::begin(*m_ptrObj); }
    typename T::const_iterator end() const { return std::end(*m_ptrObj); }
};

struct Element
{
    vector<int> m_attr;
    IteratorCapsule<vector<int>> m_attr_iter_capsule;

    Element() : m_attr_iter_capsule(m_attr) {}

    const IteratorCapsule<vector<int>> &getAttributes() const
    {
        return m_attr_iter_capsule;
    }
};

struct Config
{
    vector<Element> m_element_pool;
    Config() { m_element_pool.push_back(Element()); }
};

int main()
{
    //variant A
    Config oConfigA;
    IteratorCapsule<vector<int>> oIterCapsule(oConfigA.m_element_pool[0].m_attr);
    auto iterBeginA = oIterCapsule.begin();

    //variant B -> crash 
    Config oConfigB;
    auto iterBeginB = oConfigB.m_element_pool[0].getAttributes().begin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't crash for me, also Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @john
I use "Debug and x64" for compiling/executing. when I use "Debug and x86", It does NOT crash, but it will then crash, if you try to dereference the iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try explicitly implementing `Element(Element&& x)` to see what happens.

```
Element(Element&& x) : m_attr (std::move(x.m_attr)),
    m_attr_iter_capsule (std::move(x.m_attr_iter_capsule)) // WRONG
{}
```

This is invoked when (but not only when) `Element` is constructed from a rvalue, such as in this case:

```
Element a {std::move(Element())};
```

In this case `a.m_attr_iter_capsule` will contains a pointer to the inner `Element()` (which is out of scope after that line of code)

(note that dereferencing an out-of-bound pointer is undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed that it will segfault)

In the OP's code, this line

```
m_element_pool.push_back(Element());
```

invokes `Element(Element&&)`. The problem can be "silenced" by using `emplace_back()` (but it's not the point of this answer).

To fix it, simply define explicit copy and move constructor, and initialize `m_attr_iter_capsule` appropriately; or delete those constructors using `= delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here the working solution with an explicit move-constructor and  deleted copy-assignment-operator, move-assignment-operator, copy-constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct IteratorCapsule
{
    const T * m_ptrObj;
    IteratorCapsule(const T &refObj) : m_ptrObj(&refObj) {}
    typename T::const_iterator begin() const {  return std::begin(*m_ptrObj); }
    typename T::const_iterator end() const { return std::end(*m_ptrObj); }
};

struct Element
{
    std::vector<int> m_attr;
    IteratorCapsule<std::vector<int>> m_attr_iter_capsule;

    Element(const Element&) = delete;
    Element& operator=(const Element&) = delete;
    Element& operator=(Element&&) = delete;
    explicit Element() noexcept : m_attr_iter_capsule(m_attr) { m_attr.push_back(666); }
    Element(Element&& x) noexcept : m_attr(std::move(x.m_attr)), m_attr_iter_capsule(m_attr) {}
    ~Element() noexcept {};

    const IteratorCapsule<std::vector<int>> &getAttributes() const
    {
        return m_attr_iter_capsule;
    }
};

struct Config
{
    std::vector<Element> m_element_pool;
    Config() { m_element_pool.push_back(Element()); }
};

int main()
{
    //variant A
    Config oConfigA;
    IteratorCapsule<std::vector<int>> oIterCapsule(oConfigA.m_element_pool[0].m_attr);
    auto iterBeginA = oIterCapsule.begin();
    std::cout << "Variant A: " << *iterBeginA << std::endl;

    //variant B -> works now! 
    Config oConfigB;
    auto iterBeginB = oConfigB.m_element_pool[0].getAttributes().begin();
    std::cout << "Variant B: " << *iterBeginB << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```